# Error on MongoId query with any_of and conditions on a same attribute

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, querying

When running the following MongoId query

```
Project.any_of(
  { completed_at: nil}, { :completed_at.gte => @start_date}
)
```

it produces this error:

> "This method is not prepared to handle key being a Key and serializer being not nil"

I found the validation code for this [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria/queryable/selector.rb#L127) but I don't understand what it means.

Using `.where( "$or" => [` produces the same error.

MongoId v7.1.5, Rails v6.0, MongoDB 4.4.x

Comment: Try `where(completed_at: nil).or(:completed_at.gte => @start_date)`

Comment: There wasn't a test case covering this combination and thus it was left unimplemented. What is in `@start_date`?

Comment: @start_date is a Date instance. Also, before this filter condition there is another one with an end_date and a scope applied that works on this attributes, too but the smaller query that produces the error is  "Project.any_of ..." and the filter I posted above.

Comment: @Stefan that seems to work, thx!

Comment: @D.SM BTW, this query was working on a very old mongoid version, 3.1.4, and in the migration process to v71.5  I saw the error

Answer (score 0):

The generic string for this to be like this :

criteria.any_of({ **:field1 => "value"** }, { :field2 => "value2" })

Answer (score 0):

This is [an issue in Mongoid](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-5033)..